# Ignore whitespace in parser only

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm using the [JSON grammar from the antlr4 grammar repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4) to parse JSON files. It works fine and ignores whitespace with the usual rule: `WS: [ \t\n\r] + -> skip;`

I want to re-use the lexer to identify all tokens for syntax highlighting in eclipse. It requires to specify whitespace tokens as well, but calling `JSONLexer.nextToken()` skips over them.

Is there a way to **not** skip whitespace when using the lexer directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
WS: [ \t\n\r] + -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Instead of discarding whitespace completely, it will still create `WS` tokens, but they'll end up on a separate channel (named `HIDDEN`). The parser can only *"listen"* to a single channel, but the lexer still allows you to retrieve tokens from any channel.